# Issues with making Dynamic Downloading Link

Tags: php, dynamic, download

please i need help with this script. I have this php script named download.php. What i'm trting to do is that i want to make all my downloads link to this page i.e i want to make it dynamic. Also anytime i click the link it actually plays the MP3 instead of showing "Save As" for the User.

1) Please how can i make the script dynamic, so that this script works for all my downloading.

2) How do i make it download instead of playing/showing the file.

Thanks

```
   <?php
   $filename = 'download.mp3';

    header('Pragma: public'); 

    header('Expires: 0');

header('Cache-Control:must-revalidate,      post-check=0,pre-check=0');

 header('Cache-Control:private', false); 

   header('Content-Type:audio/mp3');

                header('Content-Disposition:         attachment;filename="'.basename             ($filename).'";');

      header('Content-Transfer-Encoding:        binary');

        header('Content-Length:'.filesize(            $filename));

     readfile($filename);

    exit;
    ?>

 HTML
 ======

 < a href="download.php"> MP3 </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's take this step by step.

1)Making the script dynamic is easy.  There are two ways:

a) Make the filename come up in a $_GET. example:

```
$file = $_GET['file'];
```

A link can be

```
<a href="download.php?file=somefile.mp3">Download</a>
```

b) Store your file data in a database.  A database could be like `id|filename|filesize|filetype` and you could just say `download.php?id=##` and when that id # is called it would send the filename to the page and download the file.

2) Making the file download automatically. Easy!

```
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
```

Replace your Content-Type with this and you should be golden.  Forced downloads don't need a file type, they just know they need to download, NOW!

Hope this helps =)